# How do I run multiple projects in android studio 2.x+?

Tags: android, android-studio

I see lots of ways of doing this on older verisons of android none of which apply to the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the location in Preferences->Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Open project in new window.

HOORAY!

Answer (score 0):

try this,may be helpful
[image: this may be helpful]

//at least 35 characters at least 35 characters at least 35 characters